# hMailServer --> find all bounced back emails

Tags: email-server, sql

I've been assigned to clean up some of our obsolete client's email from database.

So the process was to send all client an email and see which one bounces back.

now the problem is I can't find where the bounced back emails on sql server are stored.

The mail server is called hmailServer and its running on windows server 2008.

Any suggestion where I Could find em?

Comment: according to a quick search you find the logs in the installation directory: f.e. "C:\Program Files\hMailServer\Logs"

Comment: @DennisNolte yes the logs are there, but I can't find anything relating to bounced back mails.

Comment: You shouldn't have been sending all those emails in the first place. Using just `EHLO`, `MAIL`, and `RCPT` commands you can verify an address without bothering all the clients with unnecessary emails.

Comment: @kasperd ehlo mail, rcpt are way too unreliable, eg. it won't for server that requires password

Comment: @nafas Your last comment give me the impression you should hand over this task to somebody with more knowledge of how SMTP works. Setting the MX for a domain to require password in order to receive emails would block the majority of legitimate emails, so of course that isn't done.

Comment: @kasperd MX record check had been done mate, it indeed did reduce the task from 30k emails to about 12k emails, however the rest of procedure (EHLO,MAIL FROM and RCPT TO) proved to be no guaranteed. that's why we had to send emails to those of 12k.(I should have probably added this info in my question as well)